# Add data from file into ArrayList and sorting

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, io

I am trying to take data from a text file containing Strings and Integers into an ArrayList, and then sort it (which will depend on the integer values).

The text in the file pattern looks like this "Höllviken;23642". Seperated by a ";" character.

So far I've gotten this:

```
public class SorteraOrter{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    // scans file orter
    File stad = new File("C:\\Users\\Johan\\Desktop\\orter.txt");
    Scanner n = new Scanner(stad);


    ArrayList<Object> city = new ArrayList();

    while(n.hasNext()){
        String ln = n.nextLine();
        String[] arr = ln.split(";");
        Ort ort = new Ort(arr[0],Integer.valueOf(arr[1]));
        city.add(ort);
    }
    System.out.println(city.toString());

    }
}
```

For sorting i have declared some methods and made a compareTo method to use with sort. 
:

```
package soter_orter;

public class Ort implements Comparable<Ort> {

    // fields
    private int postnr = 0;
    private String ort = "";

    // constructor 
    public Ort(String s, int p){s = ort; p = postnr;}

    // method names
    public int postnr() {
        return postnr;
    }

    public String ort() {
        return ort;
    }

    public int compareTo(Ort o){
        return o.postnr - postnr;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ort + " " + postnr;
    }
}
```

So to do this first i have to succeed in adding these Strings and Integers into my ArrayList. I also need to have them connected in some way since the number and the text file belong to eachother.

My current problem is the output im getting after trying to move the file-input to the ArrayList -

> [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]

I've come a bit further and added the elemets of my ArrayList to an Object Array. I am able to sort this but unable to view it using my toString method.

```
    Object[] arr = new Object[city.size()];

for (int i = 0; i<city.size(); i++){
    arr[i] = city.get(i);
}

Arrays.sort(arr);
for (Ort o : arr){

}
```

I am unable to print this in the for loop. I get the message: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Ort"

So, so far I am unable to print the ArrayList neither the Object Array.

Comment: there is no reason for this question to be negatively marked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor in Ort class should be

```
public Ort(String s, int p){ort=s;  postnr=p;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor ir wrong.

replace

```
public Ort(String s, int p){s = ort; p = postnr;}
```

for

```
public Ort(String s, int p){ort = s; postnr = p;}
```